# Open a native app by using deep linking method in slack by using java

Tags: java, spring-boot, slack

I want to open native slack app by using a rest API. for that I'm using "slack://open" this a method of deep link into slack. for that how to call it in java code?

I'm using rest template and response entity for calling that method in my code and open native app. I'm calling this method as post method in browser directly.

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

 URI url = new URI("https://*****.slack.com/app_redirect? channel=***");

 ResponseEntity <String> entity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
```

by just pass slack://open method as url in browser it open a native slack app but when I pass get method url of my method it returns a blank page but it returns a response code as 200 in console. What mistake I'm doing?

Comment: I don't think a POST will work. You can either do a redirect or open a new page with the URL directly. Both actions must happen in the browser. Also I think your syntax is incorrect. Its: `https://slack.com/app_redirect?channel=C0VD1QBZB`.

Comment: url of this method is calling from the browser itself but when I typed "https://myworkspacename.slack.com/app_redirect?channel=CH45K7A" in the browser It open slack app. with redirected channel but when I try to call that using java code with restTemplate it displays a blank page it doesn't work I don't know where I'm wrong.

Comment: don't know how the restTemplate works, but this is not an API call between two services. You are opening an URL in a browser. If you know how to open any web page in a browser via your Java app this will work the same.

Comment: Thanks for your response @ErikKalkoken use java.lang.runtime class for open this api in web browser.